# How to get html5 session storage to textbox?

Tags: html

I tried to retrvie and display html5 session storage in text box like this

```
  <script>
     // alert(sessionStorage.param1);
    var rightbox=document.getElementById("from");
    var two=sessionStorage.getItem(param1);
    rightbox.innerHTML=two;
      </script>
```

But its not working.Alert is working fine.
What I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get you, but does this solve your problem?

Javascript:

```
  <script>
     // alert(sessionStorage.param1);
    var two=sessionStorage.getItem(param1);
    document.getElementById('from').value = two;
      </script>
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="from" name="from" value="" />
```

Comment: This is what I expect.But in phonegap I cannot get the value.always textbox is empty?